# Hybrid OpenMP/MPI matrix multiplication

Tags: mpi, openmp

I would like to do matrix multiplication by traditional way which is block, one MPI task which spawn thread, my problem is how define send and when receive results from OpenMP. if any one can help me will be great even a simple sample will be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are different ways you can approach this problem.  One is to break up the first matrix into groups of rows, and send one group to each rank.  From there, use OpenMP to parallelize the multiplication.  Finally, recombine the results into a single matrix.  Using this approach, you could use MPI_Send to send the groups out to each rank.  Assuming rank 0 has the full matrix, you would use something like:

```
float A[ndim1*ndim2];
float B[ndim2*ndim3];
float C[ndim1*ndim3];

nrows=ndim1/nranks;

for (int i=1;i++;i<nranks)
{
  startrow=nrows*i;
  nelems=nrows*ndim2;
  if (i==nranks-1)  // Better ways to do this, but this is a simple example
  {
    nelems+=(ndim1%nranks)*ndim2;
  }
  MPI_Send[&A[startrow], nelems, MPI_FLOAT, i, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
}
```

Notice that this starts with rank 1, there's no need to send from rank 0 to itself.  But we'll have rank 0 working on part of the matrix as well.

To receive in each of the ranks, use

```
nelems=nrows*ndim2;
if (myrank==nranks-1)
{
  nelems=(ndim1%nranks)*ndim2;
}
MPI_Recv(localA, nelems, MPI_FLOAT, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
```

You'll just need to copy the first nrows of A into localA directly.  You'll also need to send the entire B array to each rank, as well as needed dimensions (unless these values are already there from other means).

Once all of the data is in each rank, split the rows using OpenMP to handle one row at a time.

```
#pragma omp parallel for private(iA,iB,iC)
for (int i=0;i<localnrows;i++)
{
  for (int j=0;j<ndim3;j++)
  {
    for (int k=0;k<ndim2;k++)
    {
      iA=i*ndim3+k;
      iB=k*ndim2+j;
      iC=i*ndim2+j;
      localC[iC]=localA[iA]*B[iB];
    }
  }
}
```

Then pass the localC arrays back to rank 0 similarly to how localA was passed, swapping MPI_Send and MPI_Recv.